# Does the Roman-Catholic Church recognize the Quinisext Council?

Tags: catholicism, ecumenical-council

Does the Roman-Catholic Church recognize the [Quinisext Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinisext_Council) and admit its proceedings and canons nowadays?

I know that it was rejected by Pope Sergius I. But at the same time this Council was accepted by the East for a long time before the East–West Schism. And nowadays the Catholic Church has made a lot of steps towards reunion with Eastern Orthodox Churches, so perhaps the Church's entire attitude to this Council has changed?

Comment: I am still doing research to provide a more complete answer, but the article you provide states that Pope Sergius I instituted the singing of the Angus Dei and the breaking of the host to combat some of what was said at this council, and those two things are still practiced at every mass so it would seem at first glance that the Church has not "admitted its proceedings." More to follow...

Answer (score 3):

This [article](http://www.unamsanctamcatholicam.com/history/79-history/518-quinisext-council-in-trullo.html) gives much more detail on the historical context of the council and what was discussed there, but the answer to your question lies in the last few paragraphs:

> The patristic Church never accepted the idea of a sexually active
>   priesthood, and the Quinisext Council in Trullo certainly does not
>   represent apostolic teaching.

And this [Q&A](http://www.ewtn.com/v/experts/showmessage.asp?number=443712&Pg=&Pgnu=&recnu=) seems to indicate that the canons were integrated into the Byzantine Rite, but no others in the Catholic Church.

Comment: That's interesting. But it contradicts with the known practice: (1) in Latin rite permanent deacons can be married; (2) in Eastern Rite within Catholic Church priests and deacons can be married. These two points aren't exceptional cases.

Comment: Well point one deals with the deaconate and this quote deals specifically with the priesthood, so no contradiction there. As for point two, the second link I provided seems to indicate that Eastern rites (Byzantine at the least) are somewhat of an exception - so not a contradiction as you say, but more of an exception to what the overall "patristic Church" accepts as the first article would say.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to provide an answer, but can not yet accept it, as I would like to receive more information. In particular, I can not accept a statement that Eastern rite is something exceptional for the Catholic Church. At least nowadays. And yes, I am talking about doctrine. May be I am wrong, but to refute me one should provide link to the official document where it is said.

Comment: P.S. I would agree that *exception* would be married priesthood in Latin rite. This is practiced for priests who were formally ordinated in the Anglican Church, but then decided to join Catholic Church (and were re-ordinated again and priests within Latin rite, but still married).

Comment: Does the website you cited represent the Magisterial opinion?